# NumberPicker.getValue() on SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, might not be the last updated value

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm using the below function to detect the last final value when user complete their scroll select on NumberPicker. The getValue() would then get the latest value updated.

```
    numberPicker.setOnScrollListener(new NumberPicker.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int value = numberPicker.getValue();
            }
        }
    });
```

However, then I found out that, in the event the scroll-touch end not on a definite position of a value, but in between 2 values (e.g. between 1 and 2, but slightly closer towards 2), after letting go the scroll, the function trigger captured the getValue as 1, but the scroll will auto-complete it's scroll to centralize at 2. Therefore the last updated value of the NumberPicker is then set to 2 (not 1 i.e. as was captured in my function above).

How could I get the last updated value of the NumberPicker? Or perhaps a way to detect the final auto scroll of the NumberPicker (when it is centralizing to a specific value)?

FYI. One option is to use `setOnValueChangedListener`. However this is not ideal for my case, as it capture every single value change even the NumberPicker scrolling is in progress.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am wondering if you have fixed your issue?

Comment: The best solution i found is from @Moral Teacher
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041759/8316661](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041759/8316661)

Comment: the best solution i found is from @Moral Teacher [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041759/8316661](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041759/8316661)

Answer (score 8):

To solve this, I add both OnValueChange and OnScrollListener to NumberPicker. I made private field to keep current scroll state. Both listener interfaces are implemented by same class. onValueChangeListener method checks scroll state, and if it's idle - execute some code. This works for me. Looks something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NumberPicker np;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
        PickerListener listener = new PickerListener();
        np.setOnScrollListener(listener);
        np.setOnValueChangedListener(listener);
    }

    private void update(){
        //your code here
    }

    private class PickerListener implements NumberPicker.OnScrollListener, NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {
        private int scrollState=0;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker view, int scrollState) {
            this.scrollState=scrollState;
            if (scrollState==SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                update();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            if (scrollState==0){
                update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think update method will run two times. After scroll ended fires, value changed fires.

Comment: Small change in scroll position can trigger an update

Answer (score 1):

After so many years, this seems still a known challenge? I feel the last value should be what users intend to use in most of the cases.  I wish the Android ADK could make it easier ...

Anyway, I found the solutions above are acceptable but I use the following evolved from all the above:

```
myPicker.setOnScrollListener({ picker, state ->
            if(state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                picker.postDelayed( { // to make sure value is in picker regardless the order of scroll or value change events
                    val newVal = picker.value
                    // use the value and  hidePicker()
                }, 500)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I little bit improved @denis-ilatovskiy 's answer. This one doesn't trigger updates for small changes in the scroll position.

```
abstract class NumberPickerListener : NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener, NumberPicker.OnScrollListener {

    private var isValueChanged: Boolean = false
    private var newValue: Int = 0

    override fun onValueChange(picker: NumberPicker?, oldVal: Int, newVal: Int) {
        isValueChanged = true
        newValue = newVal
        onValueChanged(newVal, false)
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChange(view: NumberPicker?, scrollState: Int) {
        if (isValueChanged && scrollState == NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            onValueChanged(newValue, true)
            isValueChanged = false
        }
    }

    abstract fun onValueChanged(value: Int, completed: Boolean)

}
```